# Why when I upload a project in zip file from github all non english characters are displayed wrong?

Tags: python, github, encoding, character-encoding, pycharm

I am awfully sorry if it is not very smart question. I have a problem with encoding when downloading files from github which contains cyrillic (not English) characters.
I just copy paste code from PyCharm to github files, in github all cyrillic characters looks right, but when I download all files as zip archive from github, then unpack it, I see that my program GUI has unknown characters (like *"3!вц) . When I just copy paste files from PyCharm to any local folder in my PC I have no problems.
Link to the project:
 https://github.com/ArtyomKozyrev1989/workingtime_counter

Previously I have never used not English characters in my projects, so I have no idea what to do to solve the problem.

Comment: I get them all right (russian and english) and encoding set is `UTF-8`. See what encoding do you get when you extract to files.

Comment: @DinkoPehar thanks you, I started to upload files by git (from pycharm), rather than manually, now I have no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the problem you should upload files to github by git, rather than manually - it lead to problems.